How can I dynamically adjust the zIndex to keep a dragged rectangle on top without using arbitrary zIndex values?
When dragging a rectangle from the upper HStack (red rectangle) to the lower HStack, the dragged rectangle goes behind the views of the lower HStack, despite adjusting the zIndex with (.zIndex(isDragging ? 1.0 : 0.0)). I don’t want to use arbitrary zIndex values like 10 or 100. I need a solution that logically adjusts the zIndex to ensure the dragged view stays on top without hardcoding unnecessary values.

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var array1: [CustomType] = [CustomType(value: 1, color: .red), CustomType(value: 2, color: .red), CustomType(value: 3, color: .red)]
    @State private var array2: [CustomType] = [CustomType(value: 4, color: .blue), CustomType(value: 5, color: .blue), CustomType(value: 6, color: .blue)]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Spacer()
            
            MyHstackView(array: $array1)
            
            Spacer()
            
            MyHstackView(array: $array2)
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}



struct MyHstackView: View {
    
    @Binding var array: [CustomType]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(array) { item in
                RectangleView(customType: item)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Rectangle().strokeBorder(.black, lineWidth: 1.0))
        .background(Color.yellow)
        
        
    }
}

struct RectangleView: View {
    
    let customType: CustomType
    
    @State private var currentOffset: CGSize = CGSize()
    @State private var lastOffset: CGSize = CGSize()
    @State private var isDragging: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(customType.color)
            .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
            .overlay(Text(String(describing: customType.value)).font(.body.bold().monospaced()))
            .overlay(Rectangle().strokeBorder(.black, lineWidth: 1.0))
            .zIndex(isDragging ? 1.0 : 0.0)
            .offset(currentOffset)
            .gesture(dragGesture)
        
    }
    
    private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: .zero, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged { gestureValue in
                
                isDragging = true
                
                currentOffset = CGSize(
                    width: gestureValue.translation.width + lastOffset.width,
                    height: gestureValue.translation.height + lastOffset.height
                )
                
            }
            .onEnded { gestureValue in
                
                lastOffset = currentOffset
                isDragging = false
                
            }
    }
}



struct CustomType: Identifiable {
    
    init(value: Int, color: Color) {
        self.value = value
        self.color = color
    }
    
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var value: Int
    var color: Color
}


The scope in which zIndex operates is very limited and only works inside the same layout container.

In your example, the zIndex only works for instances of RectangleView in the same HStack.
You have two HStack inside a VStack. The layering of these two HStack is determined by their layout order, so the second HStack is always "higher" than the first.

See .zIndex() only applying to sibling views inside VStack but not to views outside for more elaboration.

As a half-fix, you can apply a zIndex to the HStack:
VStack {
    Spacer()
    MyHstackView(array: $array1)
        .zIndex(2)
    Spacer()
    MyHstackView(array: $array2)
        .zIndex(1)
    Spacer()
}

This fixes the drag issue when dragging from the first HStack over the second. But now the problem exists in the opposite direction, so it's not much of a fix.
Making the zIndex of the HStack dynamic doesn't solve the problem either. For example, if the zIndex of the first HStack would be raised when one of its squares is being dragged, this would work for dragging a square over the second HStack. It would also work when applied to the second HStack for a drag in the opposite direction. However, at end of drag, a square that had been dragged from the first to the second HStack would disappear under the background of the second HStack.

What I expect you probably want, is for a square to stay above the yellow backgrounds of both HStack after a drag has ended. One way to achieve this is to use .matchedGeometryEffect:

The two HStack can be changed to hold simple placeholders. The placeholders are used as the source for .matchedGeometryEffect.
The squares themselves are shown in an overlay over the VStack. The squares are matched to the placeholders, which determine their positions.

This way, all squares belong together in the same container (so zIndex works between squares) and the squares are all higher in the layout order than the yellow backgrounds (so the squares are always above the yellow backgrounds). For now, let's still allow a square to go behind other squares after drag has ended (depending on layout order).
Implementation notes:

Matched geometry effect requires a common namespace. This needs to be defined in ContentView and then passed to the containers and to the squares.
The ids of the squares can be used as the ids for the matched geometry effect.
The size for the squares can be determined using .matchedGeometryEffect too. So the size only needs to be applied to the placeholders, not to the draggable squares.
The array passed to MyHstackView does not need to be passed as a binding (at least, not for the purpose of this example).

ContentView
@Namespace private var namespace

VStack {
    Spacer()
    MyHstackView(array: array1, namespace: namespace)
    Spacer()
    MyHstackView(array: array2, namespace: namespace)
    Spacer()
}
.overlay {
    ForEach(array1) { item in
        RectangleView(customType: item, namespace: namespace)
    }
    ForEach(array2) { item in
        RectangleView(customType: item, namespace: namespace)
    }
}
.padding()

MyHstackView
let array: [CustomType]
let namespace: Namespace.ID

HStack {
    ForEach(array) { item in
        Color.clear
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item.id, in: namespace, isSource: true)
    }
}
// + other modifiers, as before

RectangleView
let customType: CustomType
let namespace: Namespace.ID

Rectangle()
    .fill(customType.color)
    // .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0) //  not needed
    .overlay(Text(String(describing: customType.value)).font(.body.bold().monospaced()))
    .overlay(Rectangle().strokeBorder(.black, lineWidth: 1.0))
    .zIndex(isDragging ? 1.0 : 0.0)
    .offset(currentOffset)
    .gesture(dragGesture)
    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: customType.id, in: namespace, isSource: false) //  added


If you wanted a dragged square to stay above all the other squares after drag ends, then:

either, set the zIndex on the dragged square to a value higher than the other squares (an incremental counter could be used for this),
or, change the order in which they are shown in the overlay, with the last-dragged square being shown last. A single array of all items could be used for this, possibly defined as a computed property. The ordering of the items in the array should be determined by the order in which they were dragged.


Why do we need Color.clear, and why do we need a duplicate of items—one with color and one without? As a reminder, by dragging an item from a stack, we are not losing its position or existence in the stack, so I believe there is no need to duplicate the view. I liked the new way you mentioned about matchedGeometryEffect to solve some issues. I need to analyze more about it and your code. I need some time to process your answer. Thanks.

@swiftPunk The views are not duplicated, there is still only one instance of each RectangleView. As for the placeholders, these are not seen, they are only used to define the size and position for the draggable squares. So the simplest implementation is to use Color.clear.
